# Increase width and height of Checkbox in CheckboxListTile

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am using `CheckboxListTile`. I just want to increase the size of the `Checkbox`, without affecting the size of overall `CheckboxListTile`. If it were `Checkbox` only widget, I would have used `Transform.scale` to increase the widget size.

Is it possible to achieve what I want? Or i would have to use `Checkbox`?

Thanks

Comment: Failed to find any exposed method. You can create custom widget

Answer (score -1):

As mentioned here (https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/CheckboxListTile-class.html#instance-properties) there is no any property or method provided by CheckboxListTile to control size of Checkbox. So, having a custom tile with checkbox makes more sense here.
Something like in code below:

```
Row(
    children: [
            Transform.scale(
              scale: 1.5,
              child: Checkbox(value: mail, onChanged: (value) {}),
            ),
            Text(
              "Check Me",
            )
          ],
        ),
```

Also wrapping the row in Inkwell with `onTap` changing state similar to that of `onChanged` in Checkbox will have almost same experience as CheckboxListTile where tapping on any part of tile checks or unchecks the box.

You can even use a ListTile with a CheckBox. The source code for CheckboxListTile (https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/52b3dc25f6/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/checkbox_list_tile.dart#L124) exactly does that. Be sure to use on tap with handlechange as done in the source to get the effect of value change on tapping anywhere in the tile.

Comment: Perhaps you didn't read my post carefully. I m not talking about `Checkbox` widget, I am talking about `Checkbox` in `CheckboxListTile` widget.

Comment: @WatsMyName I said that there is no way to control size of `Checkbox` in `CheckboxListTile`. So, its better that you look at the implementation of `CheckboxListTile` (which is basically `Checkbox` inside `ListTile`) and then implement similar widget of your own.